# How to search for audiobooks narrated by the author?

Tags: search-engine

How should I search for audiobooks narrated by their author? Are they ‘auto-narrated’, ‘self-narrated’, ‘author-narrated’, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is to find audiobook sharing websites that have an advanced feature for narrowing the search result to "narrated by Author". Seems like [simplyaudiobook](http://www.simplyaudiobooks.com/audio-books-narrator/Author+/nrt/22952/) provide this feature

Also you can simply search in google "audio book narrated by author" and find many personalized lists such as:

http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/37378.Audio_Books_Narrated_By_Their_Authors
http://modernmrsdarcy.com/authors-reading-their-own-work/